# Can I track how many an IP and user agent is blocked by .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I have denied access to some IP's and user agents through .htaccess. I want to know is there any way to check how many times one ip or user agent is blocked by .htaccess.

Comment: Check your access logs

Answer (score 0):

it should appear in your apache logs if you grep by IP or User agent ( assuming that those fields are logged. ) if you .htaccess is setup to return a 403 for those requests.